# Is there some in-code profiling of CUDA program

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvprof

In OpenCL world there is function [clGetEventProfilingInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventProfilingInfo.html) which returns all profiling info of event like queued, submitted, start and end times in nanoseconds. It is quite convenient because I'm able to `printf` that info whenever I want.

For example with [PyOpenCL](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/) it is possible to write code like this

```
profile = event.profile                                                                
print("%gs + %gs" % (1e-9*(profile.end - profile.start), 1e-9*(profile.start - profile.queued)))
```

which is quite informative for my task.

Is it possible to get such information in code instead of using external profiling tool like [nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#nvprof-overview) and [company](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/)?

Comment: the cudaEvent system can give you the equivalent of `profile.end-profile.start` via `cudaEventElapsedTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For quick, lightweight timing, you may want to have a look at the [cudaEvent API](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/).

Excerpt from the link above:

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);


cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaEventRecord(start);
saxpy<<<(N+255)/256, 256>>>(N, 2.0f, d_x, d_y);
cudaEventRecord(stop);

cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float milliseconds = 0;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

printf("Elapsed time: %f ms\n", milliseconds);
```

If you want a more full-featured profiling library, you should look at [CUPTI](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/).

Answer (score 1):

There is not a tool other than `nvprof` than can collect profiling data so far. However, you can harness `nvprof` in your code. Take a look at [this Nvida document](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#prepare-application).
You can use  `cuProfilerStart()` and `cuProfilerStop()` to probe just a part of your code. 
They are inside `cuda_profiler_api.h`